# WiX doesn't run bat file after installed it

Tags: installation, wix

I try to use a recipe of WiX Cookbook book to run batch file after copying it but somehow after the copy the installer deletes the folder and files and doesn't run the batch file.
The batch file would register two reg files into the registry.
I installed WixUtilExtension.dll, too.

```
<ComponentGroup Id="NewFilesGroup">
  <Component Id="A.dll64.reg" Directory="MyCommonAppDataFolder" Guid="60BDBD5E-8219-4C21-94B4-DE5F5E230C8C">
    <File Id="A.dll64.reg" KeyPath="yes" Source="A.dll64.reg" />
  </Component>

  <Component Id="B.dll32.reg" Directory="MyCommonAppDataFolder" Guid="8615ACC0-A07C-43C8-81A4-F91A8678009F">
    <File Id="B.dll32.reg" KeyPath="yes" Source="B.dll32.reg" />
  </Component>

  <Component Id="CMP_regasm_installer.bat" Directory="MyCommonAppDataFolder" Guid="5C8DBF10-6ED8-4E07-99F0-73AC43E1ACF2">
    <File Id="FILE_regasm_installer.bat" KeyPath="yes" Source="regasm_installer.bat" />
  </Component>      
</ComponentGroup>

<SetProperty Id="RunBatch"
          Value="&quot;[#FILE_regasm_installer.bat]&quot;"
          Sequence="execute"
          Before="RunBatch" />
  
<CustomAction Id="RunBatch"
        BinaryKey="WixCA"
        DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
        Execute="deferred"
        Return="check"
        Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RunBatch" After="InstallFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch files are text files, you cannot execute them directly. You need to use `cmd.exe` to interpret and execute the instructions in the batch file.